# android: facebook opengraph , Failed to generate preview for user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

before i ask my question I've searched and found these subjects and tried them all

[failed to generate preview for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794734/failed-to-generate-preview-for-user)

[Android Facebook-sdf Exception: Failed to generate preview for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025174/android-facebook-sdf-exception-failed-to-generate-preview-for-user)

[Facebook SDK failed to generate preview for user only when opengraphobject.setproperty("og:url") is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647232/facebook-sdk-failed-to-generate-preview-for-user-only-when-opengraphobject-setpr)

Also tried other posts 
maybe i have done something wrong so i screenshot every thing and show here all the code so any one can help please 
im trying to solve it for 3 days and tried every solution i found 
The error keep giving me this error

> Failed to generate preview for user

First : 
![pics from facebook App][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SQYC.png

Second: My code after several editing and trying from solutions :
i think my problem in the (object name) or (object type)
Tried so far :

> - memorize-friends:achievement
> - memorize-friends.achievement
> - memorize-friends:game.achievement
> - memorize-friends.game.achievement
> - game.achievement
> - i commented the (link) like you see in the code down below and noting effects
> - Replace (settype) from action to (OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder) .

maybe i placed them in wrong places

The Code :

```
OpenGraphObject score = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("memorize-friends:achievement");
                    score.setProperty("title", "Memorize Friends");
                    score.getData().setProperty("type", "game.achievement");
                    score.setProperty("image", "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAqoQKztX7dFuln&w=128&h=128&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-xap1%2Ft39.2081-0%2F851537_746626462071953_1666237728_n.png&cfs=1");
                    //score.setProperty("url", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ao.memorize");
                    score.setProperty("description", "Refresh Your Memory with Friends.");

                    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
                    action.setProperty("achievement", score);
                    action.setType("memorize-friends:win_a_top_score");

                    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(main_cls.this, action, "achievement")
                            .build();
                    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

i'm putting the code inside button click inside (dialog) .

Please help me

Thanks for help any way

Comment: Do you need to call `score.getData().setProperty("type", "game.achievement");`? The object type is set when you call `createForPost()`

Comment: i removed it and tried again , but the same thing -_-
thank you very much fir your help , hope you can help me